# Dynamic resizing and size adjustment on static element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to sof so please let me know if the information I have given is incomplete or insufficient.

I have to iFrames sitting side by side. I want to be able to resize them on the x-axis and when I resize one of them, the other resizes accordingly to fit the screen.

I got the resizing one of them part down but the other element does not resize specifically the  that contains "docWindow" iFrame.

Here is the relevant html (let know if insufficient):

```css
.resizable {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden
}

.resizable>.resized {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0
}

.ugly {
  background: red;
  border: 4px dashed black;
}

#container2 {
  flex: 0 0 225px;
  left: 25px;
  top: 108px;
  height: 828px;
  border: thin solid black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 225px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  background-color: #e9e9ed;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#container1 {
  flex: 1;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: thin solid black;
  border-bottom: thin solid black;
  border-top: thin solid black;
  position: relative;
  left: 245px;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: #e9e9ed;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div class="resizable ugly" id="container1">
    <iframe class="resized" frameborder="1" height="828" width="1580" id="docWindow" name="docWindow" scrolling="yes" src="placeholder_page.html" style="position:relative;"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="resizable ugly" id="container2">
    <iframe class="resized" frameborder="1" height="830" id="navbarFrame" name="navbarFrame" scrolling="yes" width="225" src="parent-nav-buttons.html" style="position:relative;"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have one of the containers positioned absolute, which makes no sense whatsoever to begin with, if you want any chance of two elements influencing each other.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and congratulations on asking a good question containing all the necessary information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid works better than flexbox for this scenario, because you can set the width of the left column to `auto` so that it adjusts to fit its contents (the resizable iframe) and set the width of the right column to `1fr` to consume all of the remaining space. Give the left iframe a specified width, and make the right iframe 100% width.

```css
.d1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: 5px;
}
.d1 iframe {
  display: block;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: yellow;
  min-width: 80px;
}
.d1 iframe:first-child {
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  resize: horizontal;
}
.d1 iframe:last-child {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <iframe></iframe>
  <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Brett, thank you for your kind words and your answer.

It seems I am not entirely sure how to get the resizing done with this solution, although i believe a grid approach will be the best.

I've modified the css and html to make it similar to what you posted and i only kept the "resizable" and "ugly" parts of the css.

Can you please provide clarification on how to combine resizing with your grid method?

Comment: My grid method includes resizing already. Did you run this snippet and see the resizing working?

Comment: Sadly, no. I can't see anything to click on to activate resizing when I run the snippet.

Edit: I am using Firefox Browser, could that be why?

Comment: I've just tried it on an Opera Browser, your method works there. I assume it worked for Safari too since that is what you used. Do you know any way I could get it to work on Firefox?

Comment: I have found through some research that resizing iFrames on a Firefox Browser is simply not possible due to a bug. I'm good using Opera so that's that, your solution does work. Thank you!

Comment: I've tested it in Chrome and Safari on Mac, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use those complex relative and absolute positioning. You only need two flex element with `felx-grow:1` and `width="100%"` and `height="100%"` for iframes. That's all.

```css
.resizable {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
  border:1px solid red;
  flex-basis: 0;  /* Aded for Safari */
}


#container2 {
  flex-grow:1;
  height: 400px;
}

#container1 {
  flex-grow:1;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex">
  <div class="resizable ugly" id="container1">
    <iframe class="resized" frameborder="1" height="100%" width="100%" id="docWindow" name="docWindow" scrolling="yes" src="placeholder_page.html"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="resizable ugly" id="container2">
    <iframe class="resized" frameborder="1" height="100%" width="100%" id="navbarFrame" name="navbarFrame" scrolling="yes"  src="parent-nav-buttons.html"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Finally if you had problem for resizing the resizable element in Safari, You may use this JS to handle resizing:

```
<script>

 function isSafari() {
    return /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
  }

// Check if the browser is Safari and then execute the code
if (isSafari()) {
  const container1 = document.getElementById('container1');
  const container2 = document.getElementById('container2');
  const dragHandle = document.createElement('div');
  dragHandle.classList.add('drag-handle');
  container1.appendChild(dragHandle);

  let startX, startWidth;

  dragHandle.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    startX = e.pageX;
    startWidth = container1.offsetWidth;
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', doDrag);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag);
  });

  function doDrag(e) {
    const newWidth = startWidth + e.pageX - startX;
    container1.style.flexBasis = `${newWidth}px`;
  }

  function stopDrag() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', doDrag);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm on a Mac, and this almost works in Chrome, but it doesn't work in Safari at all.

Comment: I added   `flex-basis: 0`  for safari. Check if it work. @BrettDonald

Comment: That makes no difference. Safari renders the iframes with the resizing handles, but when hovering over the handles the mouse cursor does not change, and attempting to resize the iframes does nothing. Safari seems to have no trouble with the snippet in my answer.

Comment: I added extra JS code to handle resize in SAFARI separately. @BrettDonald

Comment: Sad to inform you that this also does not work on Opera.

Comment: This code is only for Safari fallback. for other browsers you may need to remove `if (isSafari())` and write another function to check if the browser supports resize property and rewrite the code above with `if (supportsResizeProperty())` @ataerena